# How to export a model with fur to MMD

Tags: mmd-tools

I imported a MMD modle in to blender and added fur to it.

[image]

Now I want to export it back to MMD. The export works as such but the doesn't appear.

[image]

Also the two materials I added in Blender don't show up in MMD.

[image]
[image]

This are the MMD related setting of the material.

[image]

I'm guessing that I need to convert the fur from a Blender "thing" to an MMD "thing". But how?

I know from a different MMD model that I have, that it is possible to add fur in MMD. It uses an .emd file and .fx files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using hair particles for the fur, converting them to a mesh would probably work since MMD understands what a polygon is.

To do that, make sure your fur is rendering as an object. Remember to update the Scale, since it by default is a very small number.

[image]

Also make sure the Instance object has its origin at the base root of the hair:

[image]

Then you need to make instances real to convert each hiar into an object, this will be a very slow step depending on the amount of hair you have.

[image]

You'll likely want to combine the objects into one mesh before you export, but that should work.

I think the only other alternative would be to try to figure out how the .mmd, .emd, and .fx files work with fur and write your own exporter to convert the Blender hairs to that format. Or to reach out to creators that have done it and ask them how they did it, it's possible the tools already exists either with Blender or with other software.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not working. The reason is most likely that I don't have an Objekt with a face as you have. I Render as Path. I tried to render as Object but this didn't worked at all and was way to performance heavy for my PC to handle.